# Proper way to populate Ember.Select

Tags: ember.js

I have the following JSbin in which I am trying to create a basic ordering system using ember-data.

http://jsbin.com/ibazom/4 (update after Darshan's first comments)

Each order needs to be tied to a customer and I know I need to populate the property (eligibleCustomers) to bind to the Ember.Select, but I don't quite know where to do it.

Then I need to update the orders/new template with

```
{{view Ember.Select
  contentBinding="eligibleCustomers"
  optionLabelPath="content.name"
  optionValuePath="content.id"
}}
```

I am also getting an error when going to /orders that I can't figure out

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

Update: `App.Order.FIXTURES =[];` fixed the above error.

cross post from http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/proper-way-to-populate-ember-select/1611

Comment: Try using the non-minified libraries in development. It shows that you need to define `Order.FIXTURES`. That will get rid of null error. The rest of question is unclear to me, couldn't find `eligibleCustomers` in the source.

Comment: My intent was to bind `eligibileCustomers` to the Ember.Select, but I don't have anything implemented because I am unsure where it should go. Initially I was just thinking as an additional property on my `OrdersNewController`, but I think its wrong. Right now all customers are 'eligibleCustomers' but at some point I may need a subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `needs` to declare that your `OrdersNewController` requires the `customers` controller. Additionally create a property to help bind against that controller easily.

```
App.OrdersNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['customers'],
  eligibleCustomers: function() {
    return this.get('controllers.customers');
  }.property(),
});
```

In the corresponding `Ember.Select` you need to bind to a property like `selectedCustomer` to allow you to use when saving the record.

```
{{view Ember.Select
  contentBinding="eligibleCustomers"
  valueBinding='selectedCustomer'
  optionLabelPath="content.name"
  optionValuePath="content.id"
}}
```

For the `OrderNewController` to work you have to give it a new order object in the `setupController` so that the `description` and other properties correspond to the model for it since its an `ObjectController`

```
App.OrdersNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
    controller.set('model', App.Order.createRecord({}));
  }
});
```

Finally in the `createUser` method, the `transitionTo` is deprecated. You want to use `transitionToRoute` instead.

```
createUser: function() {
  var model = this.get('model');
  var selectedCustomer = this.get('selectedCustomer');
  var customer = App.Customer.find(selectedCustomer);
  model.set('customer', customer);
  model.set('dateOfOrder', new Date());
  model.save();

  this.transitionToRoute('orders');
}
```

Here is the updated [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ebupul/3/)

Comment: Why is it if I hit `#/orders/new` directly the Customers for the Select are not loaded? Shouldn't the `needs` specification handle the proper loading of that resource?

Comment: Yeah I didn't account for that, you need provide a similar `model` hook for that scenario.